# Error trying to add parserHook to mediawiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm running Mediawiki 1.23 and using the Syntaxhighlight plugin.  90% of the time, we use SQL as the specified language.  E.g.,:

```
<syntaxhighlight lang="sql">
   select 'foo';
</syntaxhighlight>
```

So I thought, "Why not just have a separate "sql" tag that invokes highlighter and sets the language to SQL?  I.e.,:

```
<sql>
   select 'foo';
</sql>
```

So I tried the following, but it doesn't work.  I'm probably misusing PHP and I could use some help.

In LocalSettings.php:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi/SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi.php";
```

In SyntaxHighlight_SeSHi.php I added the third setHook:

```
function efSyntaxHighlight_GeSHiSetup( &$parser ) {
    $parser->setHook( 'source', array( 'SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi', 'parserHook' ) );
    $parser->setHook( 'syntaxhighlight', array( 'SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi', 'parserHook' ) );
    $parser->setHook( 'sql', array( 'SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi', 'parserHookSql' ) );
    return true;
}
```

And finally in SyntaxHighlight_SeSHi.class.php I try to keep all the values that were coming in from the parser, but adding (or replacing) the "lang" value, and then call the original parserHook:

```
class SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi {
    private static $initialised = false;
    private static $languages = null;

    public static function parserHookSql( $text, $args = array(), $parser ) { 
        $args['lang']='sql';
        self::parserHook($text,$args,$parser);
    }

    public static function parserHook( $text, $args = array(), $parser ) {
        global $wgSyntaxHighlightDefaultLang, $wgUseSiteCss, $wgUseTidy;
        wfProfileIn( __METHOD__ );
        self::initialise();
        ...
        ...
```

When I do this, the page renders but the rendered text from the `sql` tag is "UNIQ088c1443c530026e-sql-00000007-QINU", so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

So any help with my PHP, or maybe I'm extending mediawiki the wrong way... In either case, thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, you are using MediaWiki from future? ;)

Comment: That would explain a lot.  But no, just 1.23.  Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return self::parserHook($text,$args,$parser);
```

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.  Can't believe I missed that!